# Rounding calculate value on MDX

Tags: mdx

I have MDX query generated by Tableau to OLAP cube:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS [Measures].[Summary Value]/[Measures].[Quantity SUM] 

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Quantity SUM], [Measures].[Summary Value],  [Measures].[Average] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Waiter].[WaiterName].[WaiterName].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [ProductCube] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

The problem is with calculated value - 'Avarage'. How can I round this value to two decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS [Measures].[Summary Value]/[Measures].[Quantity SUM] 
,FORMAT_STRING="#0.00"
SELECT
    (...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is changing. The calculated value of 'Average' is the same and have many decimal places.

Comment: tried it on a query over SSAS cube and works fine. You should try and do it directly in Tableau. This kind of formatting should always be done in the "front-end"(tableau, ssrs, web-app,...). Googled around for format in tableau and found this: [Tableau Documentation Format Numbers](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_specific_numbers.html)

Comment: @mxix Upvoted. For performance reasons I would use a format string or Tableau formatting rather than the Round function of at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

To force the process you could try this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER testvalue AS 
    VBA!Round
    (0.57372843213
     ,2
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[testvalue]} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Although I'm unsure if this function will be supported in Tableau.